# Get different object key from each button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to get a object key from a click.. basically I click a button I get info.1.item or info.2.item1 to display as I please

```
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
```

```js
const info = {
  1: {
    item: 1,
    item1: 2,
  },
  2: {
    item: 1,
    item1: 2,
  },
  3: {
    item: 1,
    item1: 2,
  }
}
```

I'm sure this has been answered thousands of times but I can't figure out what to search. Thanks

Comment: Any attempt from those answered questions ?

Comment: I tried to keep it simple in the example and I didn't ask it exactly right. My code uses different stuff but I think you got me on the right track. thanks

Comment: @JustinBenavidez just FYI when there's two identical answers the etiquette is to give the accepted answer to the person who answered first

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry about that I thought it would go to both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    const info = {
  1: {
    item: 1,
    item1: 2,
  },
  2: {
    item: 1,
    item1: 2,
  },
  3: {
    item: 1,
    item1: 2,
  }
 };
 $(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
  console.log(info[$(this).text()]);
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
```

Comment: Beaten to the finish line - this is a duplicate answer.  Also, there's no need for event delegation in this scenario.

Comment: @Archer Yes, it's no need. But, it's best practice to do this.

Comment: No, it's actually not.  You're attaching an event handler to the document object so that *every single click on the page* is handled, whether it needs to be or not.  It is best practice to *not* use event delegation, unless you are dynamically building the page at runtime, and even then it's still avoidable.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you can use the `text()` of the `button` element to retrieve the required property from the `info` object, something like this:

```js
const info = {
  1: {
    item: 1,
    item1: 2,
  },
  2: {
    item: 3,
    item1: 4,
  },
  3: {
    item: 5,
    item1: 6,
  }
}

$('button').click(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  
  console.log(info[text]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
```